# Magento 2 | Override title.phtml in module

Tags: magento2, phtml

I want to override this file in my custom module:

> /var/www/magento2-dev/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/templates/title.phtml

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can override it. Create a simple module like below:

Step 1: Create **registration.php** like below.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 2: Create **module.xml** like below.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create **default.xml** like below.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.title">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::title.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 4: Create **title.phtml** like below.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/title.phtml

with below content:

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$titleId = ($block->getTitleId()) ? ' id="' . $block->getTitleId() . '"' : '';
$titleClass = ($block->getTitleClass()) ? ' ' . $block->getTitleClass() : '';
$title = $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageTitle());
?>

<div class="page-title-wrapper<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $titleClass ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $titleId ?>><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></h1>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Add something to **H1** tag to test if its working or not.

Flush the magento cache and test.