How to change page title or <h1> element so they are not the same
For our product pages, the page title and  element is the same which results in some SEO issues. Is there a quick way to fix this or will this require a custom module to fix.
Example here:


You can go to this solution by changing title h1 element to h2 or as you need. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235678/magento-2-override-title-phtml-in-module

Hey,
Please try the solution provided in below link, It works for me.
Solution:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239136/how-to-dynamically-change-page-title-in-head
